# Is the hadith '160 angels are appointed over every believer' authentic?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity, malaikah

> Abu Umaamah said : the prophet said " 160 Angel's have been appointed over the believer to protect him from that which has not been decreed for him, including his eyes which are protected by seven Angel's as a vessel of honey is protected from flies. If a person were left to his own devices for even an instant, the devils would cause him a great deal of harm" .
> Al qurtubi, 20/4.

Searching Google with reference isn't giving any results in English I cannot type Arabic easily nor understand Arabic.

My question is the above hadith authentic or hasan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### إن كل نفس لما عليها حافظ
>
> There is no soul but that it has over it a protector.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 86:4](http://quran.com/86/4)</sup>

Various tafsirs including [Qurtubi](https://al-maktaba.org/book/31702/7199) and [Zamakhshari](https://al-maktaba.org/book/23627/2800) have narrated a hadith in the exegesis of this verse:

> وكل بالمؤمن مائة وستون ملكا يذبون عنه ما لم يقدر عليه. من ذلك البصر، سبعة أملاك يذبون عنه، كما يذب عن قصعة العسل الذباب. ولو وكل العبد إلى نفسه طرفة عين لاختطفته الشياطين

This has been recorded by Daylami in [al-Firdaus bi mathur al-khitab](https://al-maktaba.org/book/6072/1990).

It has been recorded with a chain and with a slight variation in the wording in [Mu'jam al-Kabir](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/9533) by Tabarani. [Haythami](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33855/2187) and others have noted that it is da'eef because of the weakness of 'Ufayr bin Ma'adan.